# showing a word splitted using a loop

Tags: python

I am struggling to show a word splitted (python). For example the word house should be showed like that:

```
H
Ho
Hou
Hous
House
```

My last try was something like that but I did not have success:

```py
word=input('give me a word')

lst = []
lst.extend(word)

i=lst[0]

for i in lst:
    print(i+chr(lst[i]))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the `word` instead by index

```
word = input('give me a word') # 'House'
for i in range(len(word)):
    print(word[:i+1])
```

Output

```
H
Ho
Hou
Hous
House
```

Answer (score 0):

a one liner solution to @Guy's answer is this:

```py
word = "House"
print("".join([word[0:i + 1] + "\n" for i in range(len(word))]))
```

Output:

```
H
Ho
Hou
Hous
House
```

Comment: You don't need the `0`, and you also don't need the `+"\n"+`, and it should be `"\n".join`, not `"".join`, or it will output one extra newline.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: @AmiraliAmirifar you can edit your answer to improve it.